# Tamura distance measure using ELKI library

Tags: algorithm, distance, elki

I am making use of the ELKI library to perform some distance measure between features.

Among other features, I am planing to implement Tamura features. From the research that I have done, this algorithm return a vector that represents three 'unrelated' features. (1st element: coarseness, 2nd element: contrast, 3rd-18th element: directional). Shall the distance between two tamura feature vectors be measured as a whole OR is it better for the distance between these three features to be measured independently (possible with different distance functions)?

Besides I read that Chisqaure and Quadratic-form distance are good algorithms to measure distance between histograms since they utilizes information across bins to retrieve more perceptually desirable results. However, I am still not sure whether such algorithms are adequate to measure the directionality histogram part of the Tamura feature. Can someone suggest a good distance function for such situation?

Thanks!